# SearchView is occupying entire actionBar Space

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

In my application i am trying to add an `searchView` in actionbar. But while clicking on the search icon searchView is expanding to the entire actionbar while clicking the key down it is coming to normalView.

While clicking on the search icon. It is coming like this..

[image]

```
But I want a behavior like this..
```

[image]

**options_menu.xml**

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    myapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    myapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="@string/search_title"/>
```

**onCreateOptions() method**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);


    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));        

    mSearchView.setBaselineAligned(false);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

please help me..Thanks in advance...

Comment: post your menu.xml and relevant code ....

Comment: I just added the code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just commented the code like this...Now it is working properly...

```
case R.id.search:
        //onSearchRequested();
        return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your `onCreateOptionsMenu()`

```
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
```

Any particular reason to write the property twice in menu.xml ?

Comment: it is used for to made search icon outside the textbox...it is giving the null pointer exception with out that...

Comment: you are using your name space and android name space both.use only your defined namespace then try. If problem still persist ,add logcat here

Comment: post your full menu.xml